# Symfony / Doctrine entity dump shows two ids, one is null

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I have an odd issue whereby an entity dumped with the 'dump' function in Symfony shows that it has two ids. One is null, the other is correct. Doing $entity->getId() returns null, but I obviously want the non-null id to be returned.

Example dump output:

```
FacilityFinancialData {#9370 ▼
 -id: null
 -facility: Facility {#2425}
 -content: "Self-pay Options"
 -customContent: ""
 -extraData: array:36 [▶]
 -secondStatus: true
 #useCustom: true
 -childName: FacilityDataChildName {#9372 ▶}
 -sectionDataType: 6
 -status: true
 #createdAt: DateTime @1484126322 {#9367 ▶}
 #updatedAt: DateTime @1553071185 {#9368 ▶}
 -id: 1415556
}
```

Has anybody seen this before or know of a way for me to access the non-null id?

These entities are related entities inside of an ArrayCollection.

Comment: show us your entity FacilityFinancialData class

Comment: maybe that entity is not persisted and that's why you have a null id

Comment: But how are there two ids in the dump()? One which is correct (I've checked, and it is persisted in the db), and the other which is null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I fixed my own problem. The issue was we had a private $id on the parent Entity, and a private $id on the sub-classed Entity. We should've just have a protected $id on the parent, and no $id on the subclasses.

Anyway, posted here in case anyone else ever sees the same issue.

(Not my codebase by the way - I just inherited it along with this weird issue)